# SQLite, any housekeeping task needed when dropping a table?

Tags: sqlite

as the title suggest, I doubt what happen if there is something that reference to the table being dropped, e.g., index of some fields of the table. Does SQLite handle this automatically? Are there any instances that database owner should be aware before execute the drop command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no housekeeping is required. SQLite handles those automatically. Whenever you execute a `DROP TABLE` command, the table definition and all associated data, indexes, triggers, constraints and permissions for that table will be deleted. Also remember that the table can not be recovered any more.

For more details you can visit below links
[DROP TABLE](http://sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) and [SQLite - DROP Table](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_drop_table.htm)